# What is the best way to retrieve JSON from URL in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, request, sails.js

So I've been using sailsjs to request json data from an external website and then posting that data to the create route. When I first run it, it will work for around 10-12 times and then the application will crash with event.js throw er; connect ETIMEDOUT

Looking for a better way to request json data from https://cex.io/api/ticker/GHS/BTC.

So I'm using sailsjs and in the file config/bootstrap.js I've added my service to run.

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

    // My
    tickerService.ticker();

    // Runs the app
    cb();
};
```

This is one of my attempts~ file api/services/tickerservice.js

```
function storeTicker(){
    console.log('Running!');

    //retrieves info from https://cex.io/api/ticker/GHS/BTC
    require("cexapi").ticker('GHS/BTC', function(param){

        console.log(param);

        Tickerchart.create( param, function tickerchartCreated (err, tickerchart) {});

    });
} 

module.exports.ticker = function(){

    setInterval(storeTicker, 6000);

};
```

Cex.io Library Github
https://github.com/matveyco/cex.io-api-node.js/blob/master/cexapi.js

Comment: Did you try using Node's HTTP API to make requests and get the JSON string data may be?

Comment: Yes I have, so far it seems to be coming down to error handling. When one request fails to retrieve the json, it throws an error and crashes the app. So I'm researching how to catch the error without crashing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used request for the module and watched for it's errors. I've also upgraded to sails v0.10.x app doesn't crash anymore :D

```
function storeTickerchart(){
    //console.log('Running!');
    var request = require("request");

    var url = "https://cex.io/api/ticker/GHS/BTC";

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            //console.log(body); //Print the json response
            Tickerchart.create(body, function tickerchartCreated (error, tickerchart) {
                if(error) console.log("Oops Error");
            });
        }
    });



} 

module.exports.ticker = function(){

    setInterval(storeTickerchart, 5000);

};
```